# A display driver has stopped working and has been recovered issue

Tags: windows-7, display-driver, laptop-display

I got this issue today where the computer first began to 'hang' and then the screen momentarily turned black and came back again with a pop up saying that the display driver stopped working and has been recovered.

The fix suggested was upgrading the drivers. So, opened the device manager and right click on appropriate device and click on `update driver`. Windows then says that the drivers are all updated.

Then, why is the issue persistent ?

I downloaded these drivers from [HP's website](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-dv4-2100-Entertainment-Notebook-PC-series/4074361?taskId=135&prodNameId=4168971&prodSeriesId=4074361&lang=en&sp4ts.oid=4168971&ac.admitted=1491805702581.1123376534.199480143&swEnvOID=4062&prodTypeId=321957&action=listDriver&swLang=13&cc=us). I remember I was told not to download drivers from the vendor's site as it may prevent HP from sending updates. I believe the drivers are outdated.

**Do I download the drivers from the vendor's website ? if yes, which one ?**

### Display Adapters

Intel Graphics Media Accelerator HD (8.15.10.1986 A)
Ati Radeon HD 4550 (8.713.0.0 B)

### Misc

Laptop: HP Pavilion DV4-2126tx
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium, 32bit

Comment: Err, Intel and ATI are 2 different vendor. Can you check which one is inside your system?

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo it is switchable. When not in AC, it uses the low power Intel. If in AC, it uses ATI. I can manually switch, too

Comment: New drivers are generally only meant to optimize new games anyway. This is less likely a driver problem if your laptop run just fine before. I would check for overheating problem

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo it had happened a loong time ago a couple of times, too, but I dismissed it as a random incident :/

Comment: Exactly, random error are usually from overheating problem.

Comment: Is it happening when you are using Intel graphics?? (without AC in your case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft provides a KB article about the issue:

**"Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" error in Windows 7 or Windows Vista**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946/en

Change the `TdrDelay` value to `8` and look if this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Check all capacitors of your graphic card. That problem may be from the capacitor.

Comment: More info would improve this.  However, the issue appears to be a known software issue.