# GPU-Z shows Intel OpenCL bug in HP laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, amd-radeon, intel-graphics

[image]

This is in relation to my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/571019/a-display-driver-has-stopped-working-and-has-been-recovered-issue) where I asked about a skipping mouse movement.
So far, I have done this:

Update my ATI Mobility Radeon 4550's drivers from ATI's website (and not HP that made my laptop as Microsoft said that the issue could be due to outdated drivers

While updating, a strange thing happened. The screen went black and there was a solitary cursor blinking on the screen like the one in P.O.S.T.. I hard reset the laptop and it is fine now.

Keep the temp as low as possible.

The temp of ATI Radeon is 60.5C, no load. I did not find any software that would display the temp of Intel Graphics Media Accelerator HD

Seeing that the mouse skipping is still persistent, I decided to download GPU-Z. First run, and I get the screen as shown above.

My question is:
1. **Is my GPU failing?**
2. If not, and if it is a software issue, **how do I solve it?**

---

### Misc

OS: Win7 Home Premium 32bit
Laptop: HP Pavilion, DV4-2126tx
Drivers:
ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4550: 8.970.100.7000
Intel Graphics Media Accelerator HD: 8.713.0.0

HP provided drivers [available here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=4168971&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4074361&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4062#11360)