# A display driver has stopped working and has been recovered

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, integrated-graphics, intel-graphics

I'm having the same issue explained on this question: [A display driver has stopped working and has been recovered issue](https://superuser.com/questions/571019/a-display-driver-has-stopped-working-and-has-been-recovered-issue)

Although I'm using Windows 8.1 x64, the problem is happening very often when I have programs like Unity, Steam or Acrobat Reader opened (It doesn't happen in-game). After a while, the screen just goes black and doesn't recover and then I need to shutdown the PC manually.

The problem has been happening since the installation of Windows (with its default drivers), I downloaded the latest graphics from Intel's download center, version: 15.28.22.3517. But the issue is still happening.

Some information from DxDiag:

```
Operating System: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600) (9600.winblue_gdr.140330-1035)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
               BIOS: Phoenix BIOS SC-T v2.2
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz (4 CPUs), ~1.8GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3932MB RAM
          Page File: 1736MB used, 6163MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.03.9600.16384 64bit Unicode

Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
           Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
              Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
               DAC type: Internal
            Device Type: Full Device
             Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0166&SUBSYS_99911019&REV_09
         Display Memory: 1792 MB
       Dedicated Memory: 32 MB
          Shared Memory: 1760 MB
           Current Mode: 1366 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
           Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
          Monitor Model: unknown
             Monitor Id: IVO0579
            Native Mode: 1366 x 768(p) (59.999Hz)
            Output Type: Internal
            Driver Name: igdumdim64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igdumdim32,igd10iumd32,igd10iumd32
    Driver File Version: 10.18.0010.3621 (English)
         Driver Version: 10.18.10.3621
            DDI Version: 11
         Feature Levels: 11.0,10.1,10.0,9.3,9.2,9.1
           Driver Model: WDDM 1.3
    Graphics Preemption: DMA
     Compute Preemption: Thread group
               Miracast: Not Supported by WiFi driver
    Hybrid Graphics GPU: Integrated
         Power P-states: Not Supported
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
       Driver Date/Size: 5/21/2014 03:03:40, 16586584 bytes
            WHQL Logo'd: Yes
        WHQL Date Stamp: 
      Device Identifier: {D7B78E66-4226-11CF-8C7D-9BB9B4C2C735}
              Vendor ID: 0x8086
              Device ID: 0x0166
              SubSys ID: 0x99911019
            Revision ID: 0x0009
```

Comment: set the value **TdrDelay** to a higher value like 8: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946/en-us

Comment: Nevermind, reinstalled the drivers and It is working now, however, the display error message is still showing up

Comment: try this beta driver: https://communities.intel.com/thread/52705

Comment: that driver is for 4th generation, i think 3rd generation isn't supported. this is really frustrating.

Comment: the latest driver for the HD4000 seams to be the .3643: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23957